# Push all project node dependencies to a private package feed

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

Currently, in a project, we're using some packages from a private registry hosted on Artifactory, along with some packages from npm.

We're trying to migrate all the packages (public and privates) to another Artifactory server, which is offline. However, when I run an npm publish command on the project, it only pushes the project itself as a package and not its dependencies.

We'd like to publish all dependencies located in node_modules one by one to the private registry so they can be accessed from any offline project. Is it possible to accomplish this?

I already tried to add the packages to bundledDependencies in package.json, but this, however, doesn't push the dependencies individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, what we did was to create a script that ran npm publish on every package in node_modules. Everything from the root of the project (Which had the corresponding .npmrc pointing to the target repository). This created a copy of every dependence on the new Artifactory.